# add_fee() is adding the fee twice on checkout total

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, cart

I am trying to add fee on the checkout page based on the field user selects.

When I use WC_cart **`add_fee()`** method, it adds the fee twice on the total whereas it shows only once on the checkout. So the checkout total is calculating wrong.

Here is the code I am trying:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge',50 );
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge(WC_Cart $cart) {
      global $woocommerce;

    $eu_array = array('BE','BG','CZ','DK','DE','EE','IE','GR','ES','FR','HR','CY','LV','LT','LU','HU','MT','NL','AT','PT','RO','SI','SK','FI','GB');

    if(preg_match("#customer_type=company#", $_POST['post_data']) ){

        if(in_array($_POST['s_country'], $eu_array)){
            $woocommerce->cart->add_discount(sanitize_text_field( 'cart_company_dis' ));
            $ship = $cart->shipping_total;
            $shipp = $ship - ($ship*100/122);
            wc()->cart->add_fee('Exclude shipping VAT', -$shipp);
        }
    }elseif(preg_match("#customer_type=customer#", $_POST['post_data']) ){
        $woocommerce->cart->remove_coupon(sanitize_text_field( 'cart_company_dis' ));

    }
}
```

The code applies the discount on the checkout page and adds fee as well based on the customer type and country.

The discount gets reduced correctly but fee is added twice.

How can I avoid this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WC_Cart method [**`get_fees()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_get_fees) to check if a particular fee is already applied in cart, avoiding the duplicated fee issue.

So your code is going to be a little changed:

```
// NOTE: 
// No need of "global woocommerce" and "woocommerce->cart" (old syntax) replaced by "WC()->cart"
// Here "$cart_obj" replace "WC()->cart" everywhere, as it included as argument in the function…

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge',50 );
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge( $cart_obj ) {

    $eu_array = array('BE','BG','CZ','DK','DE','EE','IE','GR','ES','FR','HR',
        'CY','LV','LT','LU','HU','MT','NL','AT','PT','RO','SI','SK','FI','GB');

    if(preg_match("#customer_type=company#", $_POST['post_data']) ){

        if(in_array($_POST['s_country'], $eu_array)){
            $cart_obj->add_discount(sanitize_text_field( 'cart_company_dis' ));

            $ship = $cart_obj->shipping_total;
            $shipp = $ship - ($ship * 100 / 122);

            // Getting the cart fees
            $cart_fees = $cart_obj->get_fees();
            $has_the_fee = true;

            // Iterating through each cart fees
            foreach($cart_fees as $fee_obj)
                if( 'exclude-shipping-vat' != $fee_obj->id ){}
                    $has_the_fee = false; // Has not 'Exclude shipping VAT' fee

            // Add the fee if it doesn't exist yet (avoiding duplicate fee)
            if( empty($cart_fees) || $has_the_fee )
                $cart_obj->add_fee( __( 'Exclude shipping VAT', 'woocommerce' ), -$shipp );
        }
    } elseif( preg_match( "#customer_type=customer#", $_POST['post_data'] ) ){
        $cart_obj->remove_coupon( sanitize_text_field( 'cart_company_dis' ) );

    }
}
```

*The Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer @LoicTheAztec. I think there may be a couple of typos, though -- either that or I'm misunderstanding something:  

1)  `if( 'exclude-shipping-vat' != $fee_obj->id ){}` -- appears to close the if statement before the value of `$has_the_fee` is changed.  

2) Shouldn't the test `if( empty($cart_fees) || $has_the_fee )` be instead `if( empty($cart_fees) || ! $has_the_fee )` (added ! for not) since the idea is not to add the fee if the cart already "has" it?

Comment: (p.s. Sorry I can't figure out how to add line breaks in a comment. The tip on the [editing-help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) re two spaces at the end of the line doesn't seem to work. Probably I'm just missing something obvious -- ??)